# SFH6916-- SOP-16, Half Pitch Mini-Flat Package eagle library needed

Tags: eaglecad, layout, opto-isolator

I want to use SFH6916 ( Optocoupler, Photo-transistor Output, Quad Channel, SOP-16, Half Pitch Mini-Flat Package) in my circuit.

I am using Cadsoft Eagle for layout designing.

The package description of this IC is kind of different I searched on internet but could not find anything regarding the eagle library for this.
Where I can find the package and symbol for this??
Any kind of help is appreciable.
Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, and especially with low-volume niche products, there isn't an existing Eagle library for a part, and you need to create your own. It isn't difficult; sometimes you can find a different part with the same footprint (SOIC-16 is actually pretty common) and create a new schematic symbol for it. Otherwise, you can create a new library from scratch; all of the details you need are in the datasheet.